# MySQL RSA encrypting private key

Tags: mysql, encryption, cryptography, rsa, share

I do have a rather complex sharing problem, I need to solve using stored procedures and RSA. There are teams that need a shared RSA key pair. Every user who is member of a team, gets a copy of the teams private key. To share that, the member has a pair of RSA keys as well.

So the member saves the teams private key by encrypting it with his public key.
The problem is, that this doesn't seem to work. Here is what I tried to see if it works:

```
SET @priv1 = create_asymmetric_priv_key('RSA', 2048);
SET @pub1 = create_asymmetric_pub_key('RSA', @priv1);
SET @priv2 = create_asymmetric_priv_key('RSA', 2048);
SET @pub2 = create_asymmetric_pub_key('RSA', @priv2);
SET @en_priv1 = ASYMMETRIC_ENCRYPT('RSA', @priv1, @pub2);
SELECT @pub1, @priv1, @en_priv1, @pub2, @priv2;
```

Why is the @en_priv1 NULL?

Does not make any sense to me!

Comment: Well, I found out, that I can only encrypt 245 Byte blocks. The RSA private key is 1675 Bytes long. So I have to split it up. But how do I split a VARBINARY? substring only works for strings. But converting the key before didn't work either. SET @testuvw = substring(CAST(@priv1 AS CHAR(1675) character set utf8), 0, 245); but I got an empty string

Comment: On the one hand it's time for some [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). On the other hand, it seems to me that you're trying to do something that should be solved differently. Maybe ask/search on [security.se] about your specific situation.

Comment: Yup, especially the fact that you're creating two key pairs and try to encrypt one private key with the other public key doesn't make a whole sense to me.